# Multiple File Upload Not Working Since 22.04 Upgrade

Tags: 22.04

I've searched and searched and can't find a solution.
Since upgrading to 22.04, when I'm in any app or program that is inside a browser (regardless of which browser. Have tried Chrome, Firefox and Opera) when I want to upload a file, I can only select one at a time.

Before the upgrade it worked fine.

Within the file system itself, I can select multiple files with no issue. It's only when the file system is brought up in a new dialogue box, whilst uploading from inside a browser, that I can't choose multiple files.

(I'm not able to drag and drop the files because the program I'm using does not allow for that function. That would be a workaround but is not possible with the program my work uses)

I can't find anything in the file system settings either.

Does anyone know if this can be changed so multiple files can be uploaded please?

Thanks

Comment: If not already reported, then please file a bug report for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue on all browsers and file explorers. I still don't know the solution but I did notice that the issue does not happen if you select the upload file button after selecting the set of files. The issue only happens if you choose the enter key on the keyboard.

Comment: Good observation! Hoever, I remain curious what's the root cause and how to fix it, but sure nice to have a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can select multiple files by holding shift button. Maybe change the file manager solves this problem.
Here you have a examples of file systems: [8 file managers for ubuntu](https://ubunlog.com/en/ubuntu-file-managers/)

Comment: I know to use shift. I've tried other file managers and it makes no difference.  Within the file manager itself, there is no problem to select multiple files.  It's only when within a browser page, and I want to upload from within the browser that multiple files can't be selected.